# Dynamically Changing Menu Specials With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hoping someone could show me the right direction to go with this. I'm working on a javascript project for a restaurant website. What I'm supposed to do is, show different lunch/dinner/happy hour specials at different times throughout the `day(dynamic)`. I'm thinking of arrays with specials. and something like a `getDay()` or `getTime()` method to show a certain special, but I'm not sure 100% about how to approach this.

```
    <script>
var specials = new Array();
                specials[0] = "Sunday Morning", "Sunday Lunch", "Sunday Dinner";
                specials[1] = "Monday Morning", "Monday Lunch", "Monday Dinner";
                specials[2] = "Tuesday Morning", "Tuesday Lunch", "Tuesday Dinner";
                specials[3] = "Wednesday Morning", "Wednesday Lunch", "Wednesday Dinner";
                specials[4] = "Thursday Morning", "Thursday Lunch", "Thursday Dinner";
                specials[5] = "Friday Morning", "Friday Lunch", "friday Dinner";
                specials[6] = "Saturday Morning", "Saturday Lunch", "Saturday Dinner";

function getSpecial() {
  var now = (new Date());
  var day = specials[now.getDay()];
  var hour = now.getHours();

  if (hour > 17)
    return day[2];  // Dinner
  else if (hour > 11)
    return day[1];  // Lunch
  else
    return day[0];  // Breakfast
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = getSpecial();
</script>

    <span id="output"></span>
```

This code should show a `menu special` in the span id. the `menu special` should dynamically change from a `breakfast special`, to `lunch specials`, to `dinner specials`, depending on the time of day. But it's not working. I was hoping someone could help with this. A gentleman on this site helped me a little but it's still not working. Any help would be awesome! Thank You!

Comment: I can kind of see no jQuery as a requirement, but no JSON? That's kind of like saying no numbers between 50 and 100.

Comment: Unclear question, looks like you didn't tried anything.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you planning on using a database like SQLServer or such sort, Please elaborate more since your details are still not enough

Comment: "Hey Folks Need Some Assistance" is not a suitable title on SO. Please sumarise your problem instead

Comment: The Specials will dynamically change due to the time of day. For example, on mondays from 8am-11am, the breakfast special will show on the website. After 11am, the website will change the special from the breakfast special to the lunch special. MVCNoob, totally unrelated but, I will have a form but the info from that form will be sent to a standard php server.

Comment: A title is what you make of it. if you know how to read english, you shouldnt have a problem

Comment: The title is completely non-descript, and provides no information about your problem. Fix the title. As you can see, this question will most likely be closed soon, due to the downvotes.

Comment: Title is fixed.

Comment: @Paulpro - retrieving dynamic data from server can be in XML, or even a proprietary format - json is just a convenient text format of complex data, nothing more

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is a bit vague, as you mentioned, you can do this with `getDay()` and `getHours()`.

You have a 2-deep array of specials: one array for each day of the week, and inside that, an item for each time segment of the day. We can index into the array directly with the day of the week, then use some if-else statements to get the specific time-of-day special.

One thing you might also want to do is get the time from the timezone in which the restaurant is located; the example below will just get the user's local time, wherever they are.

```js
var specials = [
  [ "Sunday morning", "Sunday lunch", "Sunday dinner" ],
  [ "Monday morning", "Monday lunch", "Monday dinner" ],
  [ "Tuesday morning", "Tuesday lunch", "Tuesday dinner" ],
  [ "Wednesday morning", "Wednesday lunch", "Wednesday dinner" ],
  [ "Thursday morning", "Thursday lunch", "Thursday dinner" ],
  [ "Friday morning", "Friday lunch", "Friday dinner" ],
  [ "Saturday morning", "Saturday lunch", "Saturday dinner" ]
];

function getSpecial() {
  var now = (new Date());
  var day = specials[now.getDay()];
  var hour = now.getHours();
  
  if (hour > 17)
    return day[2];  // Dinner
  else if (hour > 11)
    return day[1];  // Lunch
  else
    return day[0];  // Breakfast
}

document.getElementById("output").textContent = getSpecial();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for! Thank you alfred! And i'm Sorry to everyone else for the confusion of my post.

Comment: Hey Alfred! The code you posted works perfectly fine on SO"Run Code Snippet" but when i use it, it doesnt seem to work for me. i used the exact code you posted and it didn't work. I edited the array a little to see if it would work and still no dice. Here is my code

Comment: it looks like my code is too long? i've formatted code as a comment on here before and i cant remember how to do it

Comment: @RobinJennings Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. I added some more javascript and it works like a charm now.